# Pyspark filtering based on column value data and applying condition

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe in this format.

```
out.show(5)
+----------------+--------+--
|ip_address| Device  | Count |
+----------------+--------+--
|2.3.4.5  |   Apple  |     6 |
|1.2.3.4  |  Samsung |     18|
|6.6.6.6  |   MI     |     8 |
|4.4.4.4  |   Samsung|     12|
|8.8.8.8  |   Apple  |     16|
|9.9.9.9  |   Samsung|      8|
+----------------+--------+---
```

I want to get the output where output adds result which meets both the conditions

- For ‘Device’ as ‘Samsung’ the ‘Count’ >10
- else for any other ‘Device’ Type if ‘Count’ > 8

Final output should be like this

```
+----------------+--------+--
|ip_address| Device  | Count |
+----------------+--------+--
|1.2.3.4   |  Samsung|   18  |
|4.4.4.4   |  Samsung|    12 |
|8.8.8.8   |   Apple |    16 |
```

So one way I can think of doing is something like this by filtering out the Device type and  applying conditions but I want to know if we can do it using a if else and then concatenating both conditions output

```
frSamsung = out.filter(out["Device"].rlike("Samsung"))
 fpr=frSamsung.filter(frSamsung.Count > 10)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `groupBy`?

Comment: you mean groupBy Device and then perform an aggregate

Comment: second line in you exemple `|6.6.6.6   |   MI    |     8 |` should not be included because Count is 8 (it doesnt repect rule `else for any other ‘Device’ Type if ‘Count’ > 8`)

Comment: @steven you are right.Edited

Comment: @pythonNinja You have two solutions that should give you the result you expect. Mine is SQL type, Rakesh use programatic way. They're both equal. choose the one you prefer.

Comment: @Steven- So nice of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically here you need composite condition, count depends on device type with 2 different conditions -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where((
         ((F.col("device") == 'Samsung') & (F.col("count") > 10 )) | 
         ((F.col("device") != 'Samsung') & (F.col("count") > 8 )) 
)).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where(
    """
    Device = 'Samsung' and Count > 10
    or Device <> 'Samsung' and count > 8
    """
).show()
```